# microsoft custom translator deployment failed

Tags: microsoft-translator

I successfully trained a few models on the Custom Translator portal which I cannot deploy. I tried several times, but each time I start the deployment I get a "Deploymentfailed" status after a while.

Is there anything I should bear in mind or anything I can do about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the answer is either that you exceed your quota of 3 deployed models or you are trying to deploy a model in a project where a model is already deployed. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that's not the case. There's no other deployed model in my project and when I exceed my quota I get an explicit "quota reached" message, which I did not get with my "deploymentfailed" models (and, in any case, I counted my deployed models and I'm definitely under my quota).

Comment: If neither of these conditions apply the official answer I also got was that it is an issue on the translator's end. The team is working to fix it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to let you know that we have fixed the deployment process.  Please retry your deployments now.